# how to create new columns and insert the values one by one in python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas

this is what my table looks like for example

```
| Name | post code | 
| :---:| :-------: |
| james| DA4 5FH   |
| Jack | DA5 5FH   |
| john | DA6 5FH   |
```

1)i am running a for loop so for each item i want to populate on the excel/csv file by creating new columns and add values to the first row so it looks like this

```
| Name | post code | DOB. |  sport    |
| :---:| :-------: | :---:| :-------: |
| james| DA4 5FH   |1/1/20| football  |
| Jack | DA5 5FH   |
| john | DA6 5FH   |
```

2. of course in the second item from the loop i don't want to create the header again because the header DOB and sport already exist

```
| Name | post code | DOB. |  sport    |
| :---:| :-------: | :---:| :-------: |
| james| DA4 5FH   |1/1/20| football  |
| Jack | DA5 5FH   |1/1/97| basketball|
| john | DA6 5FH   |
```

how can i use panda to insert value to the next row. the first time it will include the headers but the second item will not need to insert the headers

Comment: Don't run a loop to insert data one row at a time. Run your loop to build e.g. `list_of_DOBs` and `list_of_sports` and then do `df['DOB'] = list_of_DOB`.

Comment: is it possible to run a loop to insert data one row at a time ?

Comment: insert the entire row, yes, part of it, no. It's bad practice (and bad performance) either way.

Comment: my problem is i have to make 1000 api requests to get the entire row and if my computer crash i might lose all my responses

Comment: can i insert part of the row based on id ? so i have predefined columns already

Comment: This looks like a case of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), asking about your solution rather the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

To run a loop and insert line by line, you can do :

```
Your way to loop with i:

    new_sport_value = your request result
    
    rowIndex = df.index[i]
    df.loc[rowIndex, 'sports'] = new_sport_value
```

*Pandas is not made to work like that so maybe consider working with other objects and then convert it to dataframes*

Comment: my problem is i have to make 1000 api requests to get the entire row and if my computer crash i might lose all my responses

Comment: So instead of the sports_list[i], insert your request result there and you should be fine with this code

Comment: And replace the for i in range blabla by your loop and your way to increment index

Comment: I will edit my answer so it's clear

Comment: do you have to fill in the entire row before it can appear on your table?

Comment: nope you can make it column by column, and use your dataframe with the new value at any time

Comment: give it a try and print you'll see

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
API = ["1A", "2B", "3C"] # Here is your APIs

for i in range(len(API)):
    try:
        df.loc[i, "API"] = API[i]
    except:
        print(f"The API {i}, didn't response")
```